# Netplan config file not disabling dhcp

Tags: 20.04, dhcp, netplan, static-ip

I've setup ubuntu 20.04 desktop version on a PC that has 2 NICs.  I have uninstalled network-manager and just want to simply have a static IP on each interface.

I've got the netplan .yaml file setup and it works, only problem is that there is also a .yaml file in /run/netplan/ that's being generated at every reboot and has the dhcp4 flag set to true.

This causes one of my interfaces to have two IPs, a dhcp address and the static address I want as secondary.  I don't know where this file is coming from since I have removed network-manager.

I've been reading forums and documentation all day trying to figure out how to make the DHCP address go away and I'm not having much luck.  I've tried different .yaml files, renamed them to something else that comes lexicographically later, edited the /run/netplan file, not sure what else to do.  Don't really want to go into /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf and cripple it, not sure if that will cause other issues.

Any ideas and help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file
--------------------------------
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp10s4:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.0.1.245/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [10.0.1.1,208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220]
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.100.1/24]


------------------------------------
bigdave@img-svr:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e6:ba:ee:c8:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::92e6:baff:feee:c889/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp10s4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e6:ba:ee:c6:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.157/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global enp10s4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.1.245/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global secondary enp10s4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::92e6:baff:feee:c607/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Do you have the dhcpcd package installed?

Comment: I do not, I tried uninstalling that first.  System came back and said that it wasn't installed.

Comment: *root@seafile:/etc/netplan# ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 28 11:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 104 root root 4096 Aug 28 11:41 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 652 Aug 28 11:37 50-cloud-init.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 416 Aug 27 11:56 no.50-cloud-init.yaml* If you have something like this and you assume the file with the prefix "no" wouldn't touched then you are wrong.
I had this and the 1st file had the static ip setup and the 2nd file had the dhcp.
In the end I had both a static ip and another given by dhcp for the same interface.
Looks like the netplan uses all files in /etc/netplan/ to build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your .yaml look EXACTLY like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp10s4:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [10.0.1.245/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.1.1, 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220]
      optional: true
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.100.1/24]
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I don't have the optional flag in there right now.  I didn't put a gateway or dns on the 2nd interface because I don't need them on that NIC. I can add them if you think that's causing the problem..

Comment: @BigDave2001 There are other changes in my .yaml file. Use my exact code... don't just edit your existing code. Report back.

Comment: @BigDave2001 Status please...

Comment: Still didn't work putting your exact code in there.  I re-imaged the box and tried the code again, working normally now. Thank you.